# How to put logs in WordPress

Tags: customization

Is there any way that I can log anything in WordPress similar to logs we can do it in Magento?

I am integrating a custom plugin in that I have added few functions with help of hooks, So I need to debug something in it. In this I need if I can enter any text or data into WordPress logs.

If so Please let me know the procedure for generating log into WordPress.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You can enable WordPress logging adding this to `wp-config.php`:

```
 // Enable WP_DEBUG mode
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

// Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

you can write to the log file using the [`error_log()` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) provided by PHP.

The following code snippet is a very useful function wrapper for it, make it available in your plugin:

```
if (!function_exists('write_log')) {

    function write_log($log) {
        if (true === WP_DEBUG) {
            if (is_array($log) || is_object($log)) {
                error_log(print_r($log, true));
            } else {
                error_log($log);
            }
        }
    }

}

write_log('THIS IS THE START OF MY CUSTOM DEBUG');
//i can log data like objects
write_log($whatever_you_want_to_log);
```

if you cant find the `debug.log` file, try generating something for it, since it will not be created if there are no `errors`, also in some hosted servers you might need to check where the error log is located using php info.

Comment: For easy use of the write_log function I have created it as plugin https://github.com/manchumahara/cbxwpwritelog  if that helps. I am using it everyday for development purpose.

Answer (score 11):

WordPress can do logging! Check out the WordPress debugging page here https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

I typically like to set my local development websites up to log errors in a debug file, rather than to have them output on the screen.

Head over to to your wp_config file and scroll to the bottom where it defines WP_DEBUG.

This is what my typical setup looks like:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true); // To enable debugging. Leave things just like this to output errors, warnings, notices to the screen:
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true ); // To turn on logging
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false ); // To prevent output of errors, warnings, notices to the screen (which I personally find SUPER annoying):
```

With those settings, WordPress will now log errors, warnings, and notices to a `debug.log` file located in `/wp-content/debug.log`

Log files in production environments are security threats so **IF** you decide to have logging on a production environment, it would be a good idea to set your .htaccess file to deny access to the log file (or similarly use a security plugin to block it). That way you still get your logs, but don't have to worry about hackers getting all that info as well.

Comment: Can I add any custom text in it? For example in a loop Just to get confirm which is called  I want to enter numbers like 1,2,3 etc. How can I do it

Comment: You can. Check @david's answer for how to do that :) Here's a good article on that https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/using-the-wordpress-debug-log