# Send data to 3rd party api with wp_remote_post on wp_login

Tags: hooks, actions, api, json, wp-remote-post

Is it possible to use wp_remote_post to send http post requests to 3rd party api's? I wasn't able to successfully save the user object as a javascript variable, so I was hoping I could make an http request with php and handle the javascript manipulation in my node express app.

Current attempt:

```
function identify_user() {
    echo "made it into identify user";
    if( is_user_logged_in()):
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $user = [];
        $user['id'] =  $current_user->ID;
        $user['user_login'] = $current_user->user_login;
        $user['user_email'] = $current_user->user_email;
        $user['user_firstname'] = $current_user->user_firstname;
        $user['user_lastname'] = $current_user->user_lastname;
        $user['display_name'] = $current_user->display_name;
        $response = wp_remote_post( 'myapp.com/endpoint', array(
           'method' => 'POST',
           'headers' => array('Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8'),
           'body' => json_encode($user)
        )
    );

    if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
       $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
       echo "Something went wrong: $error_message";
    } else {
       print_r( $response );
    }
    endif;
}

add_action( 'wp_login', 'identify_user' );
```

I'm having trouble troubleshooting this code because none of my echo calls are logging to the console. I've seen that you can run error_log(something) but haven't been able to get that working either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 'body' needs to be an array, not including the 'json_encode($user)' piece.

```
$response = wp_remote_post( 'myapp.com/endpoint', array(
  'method' => 'POST',
  'headers' => array('Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8'),
  'body' => $user
  )
);
```

I have this in my function since I also had issues with the body being an object:

```
if (is_object($user) && !is_array($user))
  $user = json_decode(json_encode($user), true);
$body = $user;
```

Regarding the 'run error_log(something) ...' that you are having problems with, try 
[#David Lee's wrapper function](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/260236/how-to-put-logs-in-wordpress)

Basically you can call

```
write_log('THIS IS THE START OF MY CUSTOM DEBUG');
  // or log data like objects
write_log($object_you_want_to_log);
```

I don't know what I would do without it.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code might be help to you.

```
function identify_user() { 
if( is_user_logged_in()): 
$current_user = wp_get_current_user(); 
$_id = $current_user->ID; 
$_email = $current_user->user_email; 
$user = json_encode(array("user_id"=>$_id,"user_email"=>$_email)); 
$curl = curl_init("myeNDPOINT"); 
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, true ); 
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$user); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-Type:application/json')); 
curl_exec( $curl ); 
curl_close( $curl ); 
endif; 
} 

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'identify_user');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can  try below code for wp_remote_post.might be you are missing remote post url parameter.

Also i have noticed that you are converting user variable in to json format 2 time which is wrong.

```
$response = wp_remote_post($url, array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'headers' => array('Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8'),
        'httpversion' => '1.0',
        'sslverify' => false,
        'body' => json_encode($user)
    );
```

Comment: I had forgotten to put in a dummy url for example purpoes

Comment: is wp_remote_post designed for this? or am i better off figuring out curl or ajax. i had an ajax solution but could not get the localize script function working. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/299378/send-user-data-to-3rd-party-api-on-log-in

Comment: But also you are doing json_encode 2 times. if you already json encoded user before then no need to add json encode under body tag

Comment: if you use curl then it would be best,

Comment: i forgot to delete that bit too. i'll edit my question. still nothing happening. no logs on my heroku server and no logs in web browser console.

Comment: Lets try with curl.

$curl = curl_init( $url);
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$user);
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
$response = curl_exec( $curl );
curl_close( $curl );

Comment: Also if you want to debug error with curl then look at this link how this will show the error in curl.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987006/how-to-catch-curl-errors-in-php

Comment: if this answer works, you should put it in the answer section so i can accept your answer:)

Comment: You are talking about curl answer. is it working for you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75333/discussion-between-yale-newman-and-somin).

Comment: Use wp_remote_post() which will automagically work out the best way to get out, that is, whether to use curl or allow_url_fopen.