# The plugin generated 227 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I create test plugin for learn purpose. i face this error on plugin activation.

error:
The plugin generated 227 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin.

my php file:

```
<?php
  if(!class_exists('my_class')):
class my_class{
    public function __construct(){
       
    }
    function activation()
    {
        echo "activaton function is called on activation";
    }
   
  
}



new my_class;

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array('my_class','activation'));

endif;


?>
```

Comment: It's because you're outputting text on plugin activation. You shouldn't do that.

Comment: The activation function is also not declared as static, so you should do `$my_class = new my_class;` then use `array( $my_class, 'activation' )` and not `array('my_class','activation')`.

Comment: thanks its working. but i just want to test this function is called on activation or not. how can i test this function run on activation?

Comment: Enable and use `WP_DEBUG_LOG`, check [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/260236/how-to-put-logs-in-wordpress/260309#260309) answer for details.